# EF Core generated sql query is using the entity name as table name, not the custom table name set by the table naming convention

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a custom table naming convention which prefixes B_ to the entity name. This works fine when I generate the migration scripts. However, when I execute any get method, the EF Core generated code doesn't generate the table name with the prefix. Instead it uses the Entity name itself as table name and due to this, an exception - *

*Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Appointment'*

*.- is thrown.
The query is supposed to be generated with table name as B_Appointments, which is the custom table name.

Do anyone have any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: Where and how do you apply your naming convention?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I have created a custom naming convention by implementing IEntityTypeAddedConvention. The same is applied while adding the Service registrations as given below. serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkNamingConventions();

Comment: I was asking because apparently your naming convention is not applied/is not in effect when the context is instantiated at runtime. AFAIK adding services is not enough - EF Core creates and uses its own internal service provider. Replacing service is easy, adding new one requires a lot of plumbing code. Anyway, w/o having reproducible code there is nothing we can do to help. But you can put breakpoint in the code which applies the naming convention and make sure it is hit at runtime, which I doubt.